# squid-deb-proxy or archive.ubuntu.com problem?

Tags: apt, squid-deb-proxy

Hallo I have some problem in this 6 mounths trying to update my desktop systems.
Sorry I cannot tell if is a archive.ubuntu.com server temporary problem or is a problem on my squid-deb-proxy package.

watching /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log and apt upgrade output I see:

from apt output:

```
Ign:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1                                                                                                                 
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 udev amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libudev1 i386 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libsystemd0 i386 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.1
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 64.0.3282.140-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Ign:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8
Err:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 gcc-5-base i386 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9
  Connessione terminata
Err:51 http://151.99.86.73:80/data/0189f472fb16f092/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 gcc-5-base amd64 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9
  403  Forbidden
```

from /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log:

```
1518428930.420     96 192.168.1.107 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/302 445 GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.149 text/html
1518428931.389     32 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4233 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/028979686fecdd00/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu21.1_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429050.519      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4212 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/00894e6ad5c1296b/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429050.577     57 192.168.1.107 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/302 448 GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.149 text/html
1518429170.721     68 192.168.1.107 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/302 445 GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.1_amd64.deb - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.152 text/html
1518429176.717     33 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4221 GET http://151.99.86.75/data/0089936cbd9662c9/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429290.819      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4212 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/01891f6e2a6c5119/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.1_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429290.875     56 192.168.1.107 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/302 454 GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.152 text/html
1518429410.878      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4239 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/0189e8705841ea73/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429410.969     91 192.168.1.107 TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED/302 455 GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.4.0-6ubuntu1%7e16.04.9_amd64.deb - HIER_DIRECT/91.189.88.152 text/html
1518429531.019      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4244 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/0189f472fb16f092/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.4.0-6ubuntu1%7e16.04.9_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

The system hang waiting for data.
Is this a well know problem?

My configuration:
from /etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default

```
.dl.google.com
.ppa.launchpad.net
.downloads-distro.mongodb.org
# tutti questi sono per getdeb
.getdeb.net
.mirror.lagoon.nc
.ftp.heanet.ie
.getdeb.mirror.garr.it
.archive.getdeb.net
.getdeb.megaglest.org
.mirrors.dotsrc.org
.zulu930.server4you.de
.188.138.90.189
.ftp.yzu.edu.tw
# fine getdeb
.apt.puppetlabs.com
.deb.theforeman.org
# postgresql.org
.postgresql.org
#owncloud
.download.owncloud.org
.download.opensuse.org
#tox
.pkg.tox.chat
#variety
.151.99.86.77
```

from
/etc/squid-deb-proxy/squid-deb-proxy.conf

```
acl allowed_networks src "/etc/squid-deb-proxy/autogenerated/allowed-networks-src.acl"

# this file contains the archive mirrors by default,
# if you use a different mirror, add it there
acl to_archive_mirrors dstdomain "/etc/squid-deb-proxy/autogenerated/mirror-dstdomain.acl"

# this contains the package blacklist
acl blockedpkgs urlpath_regex "/etc/squid-deb-proxy/autogenerated/pkg-blacklist-regexp.acl"

# default to a different port than stock squid
http_port 8000

# -------------------------------------------------
# settings below probably do not need customization

# user visible name
visible_hostname squid-deb-proxy

# we need a big cache, some debs are huge
# maximum_object_size 512 MB
# leonardo
maximum_object_size 2048 MB

# use a different dir than stock squid and default to 40G
# cache_dir aufs /var/cache/squid-deb-proxy 40000 16 256
# leonardo
cache_dir aufs /var/cache/squid-deb-proxy 100000 16 256

# use different logs
cache_access_log /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log
cache_log /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/cache.log
cache_store_log /var/log/squid-deb-proxy/store.log

# tweaks to speed things up
cache_mem 200 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 10240 KB

# pid
pid_filename /var/run/squid-deb-proxy.pid

# refresh pattern for debs and udebs
refresh_pattern deb$   129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern udeb$   129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern tar.gz$  129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern tar.xz$  129600 100% 129600
refresh_pattern tar.bz2$  129600 100% 129600

# always refresh Packages and Release files
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims

# handle meta-release and changelogs.ubuntu.com special
# (fine to have this on debian too)
refresh_pattern changelogs.ubuntu.com\/.*  0  1% 1

# only allow connects to ports for http, https
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 443 563   

# only allow ports we trust
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# do not allow to download from the pkg blacklist
http_access deny blockedpkgs

# allow access only to official archive mirrors
# uncomment the third and fouth line to permit any unlisted domain
http_access deny !to_archive_mirrors
#http_access allow !to_archive_mirrors

# don't cache domains not listed in the mirrors file
# uncomment the third and fourth line to cache any unlisted domains
cache deny !to_archive_mirrors
#cache allow !to_archive_mirrors

# allow access from our network and localhost
http_access allow allowed_networks

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# we don't want to clash with the squid netdb state file
netdb_filename stdio:/var/log/squid-deb-proxy/netdb.state
```

from squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl:

```
# private networks
10.0.0.0/8 
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
192.168.1.0/16
127.0.0.1

# IPv6 private addresses
fe80::/64
::1/128

# additional non-private networks can be added to the directory:
#  /etc/squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl.d
```

from /etc/squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl.d/10-default

```
188.138.90.189/17
```

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved but the reason is a mystery.

On my `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default` I have to add some ip:

- 151.99.86.73
- 151.99.86.75
- 151.99.86.77
- 151.99.86.79

Mostly are necessary because some download at `archive.ubuntu.com` resolve to `151.99.86.x/data/<exanumber>/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/...`

so when a new error reporting 151.99.86.x appears, I add a new ip to the acl file.

I like to understand why isn't use a domain address unless  151.99.86.x  and I like to understand if there is a better solution than add one IP at time when the problem rise.

regards,
Leonardo

Comment: after some time and test this is the right solutions

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parts seem to be related to IP `151.99.86.73`

```
Err:51 http://151.99.86.73:80/data/0189f472fb16f092/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 gcc-5-base amd64 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9      403  Forbidden
```

```
1518428931.389     32 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4233 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/028979686fecdd00/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu21.1_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429050.519      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4212 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/00894e6ad5c1296b/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429176.717     33 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4221 GET http://151.99.86.75/data/0089936cbd9662c9/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.1_i386.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429290.819      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4212 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/01891f6e2a6c5119/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.1_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429410.878      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4239 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/0189e8705841ea73/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apparmor/libapparmor1_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1518429531.019      0 192.168.1.107 TCP_DENIED/403 4244 GET http://151.99.86.73/data/0189f472fb16f092/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.4.0-6ubuntu1%7e16.04.9_amd64.deb - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

These requests are denied, because the destination (`151.99.86.73`) is not listed as an allowed domain. Adding this IP to /etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default should fix it. Add a line containing

```
151.99.86.73
```

and you're done.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I have do it and also delete row 192.168.1.0/16 from squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl  I wait some days to see if it work

Comment: no same problem.

Answer (score 0):

on /etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl I have delete the point '.' in front of domain.

like this .archive.ubuntu.com become -> archive.ubuntu.com

the first test go well.

I try for some time until I can see if the error come back again.

Comment: No not solve the problem. (I like to know what's the difference from address with point and without point in acl ). The error now is this:  Err:2 http://151.99.86.79:80/data/0326bce2bd9555f7/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 update-notifier-common all 3.168.9                                                                         
  403  Forbidden.
If I upgrade again all go well:
Download of:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 update-notifier-common all 3.168.9 [163 kB]